# How to get stacktrace from Jenkins using WebService API?

Tags: web-services, jenkins

Is there any way to get stacktrace from jenkins in case of build fail (for the specific job) ?

Even simple maven output will be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it is relevant anymore, but it is possible. First you ahve to get the link to a single job which can be achieved by http://[jenkinjs_server]/job/[jobname]/lastCompletedBuild/testReport/api/xml. As a result you are going to get something that consists

```html
<child>
<url>
https://ci.infonova.at/job/ProductCore/view/ALL/job/smoke-tests-gf-libs/com.infonova.product.jtf$end2end-tests/3/
</url>
</child>
```

Here you need to take that url and add 
 /testReport/api/xml?tree=suites[cases[className,errorStackTrace]].

With that tree you can add a filter, so that you get only the errorStackTrace together with the class name.

Comment: Please use markdown/backticks to make your answer more readable.

Answer (score 1):

No, since you won't get an exception for every kind of build failure.

I think the closest thing is getting the latest build console output which you can find under `http://[jenkins_server]/job/[job-name]/lastBuild/console` (replace the `[...]` parts with the actual values).